# How to retrieve AuthenticationToken while processing API request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, aspnet-contrib

I've configured [External provider authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to my Blazor WASM app. User can choose to log in via Spotify account and after that, I want my server to download some data about him from Spotify API.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt()
            .AddSpotify(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "clientid";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-spotify";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                var scopes = new List<string> {
                    //scopes
                  };
                options.Scope.Add(string.Join(",", scopes));
                options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
                {
                    List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

                    tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                    {
                        Name = "TicketCreated",
                        Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                    });

                    ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
                    ctx.Properties.IsPersistent = true;

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
```

In order to call Spotify API, I need an access token. Token is, if I understand correctly, given to my server after user logs in. In above code, I've specified `OnCreatingTicket` event and I can see it is being fired (just after I log in) and `access_token` is in `tokens` list.

Now, the problem is, I don't know how to retrieve that token later.

Here is what happens after log in:

1. User navigates to `\LikedSongs` (blazor wasm subpage that is meant to display data)
2. Blazor page calls my server's API to retrieve data that will be later displayed

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    savedTracks = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<SavedTrack[]>("UsersTracks");
}
```

3. Finally, my API controller is being fired:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<SavedTrack>> GetAsync()
{
    // here I need to have access_token
    // ASP.net MVC tutorial I follow states, that below line should work
    var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Spotify", "access_token");
    
    // unfortunately token == null
}
```

For some reason, `token` is null. And I can't find any other tokens in HttpContext. As I understand correctly, tokens are encoded in cookies, so why I can't find any of them there?

Comment: I guess you need to send token as part of http headers for every call you making from client to backend. '

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. I mean: I'm going to communicate with Spotify API through my backend only, so why would I store this token on client side?

Comment: Because the user is the owner of the token, your server is not, and you should never think otherwise

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#request-additional-access-tokens

Comment: @ChrisCampbell I'm getting _some_ access token using this example, but Spotify is telling me it's invalid. It's not probably what I'm looking for

Comment: Ok, so my temporal solution to this problem is: I'm saving token to cookie while in `OnCreatingTicket` event (which seem to handle callback from Spotify auth server) and now all requests from client to my backend contain this cookie (which can be then read by my server and used to make requests to Spotify). I have completly no idea if that's the way I should do it (probably not, token refreshing is non existent), nor if it's safe (maybe? assuming I'm working on https no one sees my cookies?). I'll update if I find some better sources, official docs are really laconic on this topic.